# What type of power steering fluid do I use in my 1987 Dodge Dakota, 3.9 L, 2 wheel drive pickup?

Tags: dodge, power-steering, dakota

1987 Dodge Dakota power steering fluid type ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this pdf](https://www.cardone.com/docs/default-source/product-pgs/psfluidtypes.pdf?sfvrsn=16), all pre-1998 Chrysler/Dodge vehicles should be using plain old power steering fluid. Those after 1998 should be using ATF-4 unless specified differently.

NOTE: The Crossfire should use Pentosin CHF 11S.